# Error with focus in IE - js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, razor, popup

I'm working on a MVC project.

By default all dropdowns of PopUps comes with auto focus on.

When charging a PopUp with a dropdown field gains focus.

I tried to remove it using a jquery selector.

Firefox works removing the autofocus.
IE does not work.

What can I do?

```
$("input:not(.dropdown)[type=text]:first", popup).focus(100);
```

Comment: Seems a bit hacky but would, `$("input:not(.dropdown)[type=text]:first", popup).focus(100, function () { $(this).blur(); });` work?